# Analytical derivatives for noise

Tags: procedural-generation

Lately i'm doing lot of research regarding procedural terrain generation. I do a lot of learning from www.iquilezles.org. I'm now familiar with such things as perlin/simplex noise, fbm, domain warping, etc. But right now I'm looking into this > https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/morenoise/morenoise.htm and am very clueless what are those derivatives, what do they represent and how to use them. Maybe someone can put this knowledge in more simple words or/and illustration? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with [the concept of a derivative in calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative)?

Comment: Kind of and I'm studying it right now to refresh my knowlage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of a function gives you the slope at each point of said function (it actually gives you the rate of change, but the two are identical for the first derivative)

For instance if you have the function \$f(x)=x\$, the derivative would be \$f'(x)=1\$, since the slope of the function is 1 at every point. Similarly for \$g(x)=x^2\$ it would be \$g'(x)=2x\$.

Knowing the slope of a function at any specific point is great, because it can be used to calculate the normals of the function, which can then be used to do lighting and other stuff, the article gives you a couple of ideas.

The second derivative is a bit harder to use in this context. It generally allows us to get the local minimums and maximums of any function by looking for coordinates where the second derivative is 0 and the signs of the values on the sides are different.

Comment: But the function returns 3 derivatives.

Comment: Another q. You wrote g′(x)=2x. So if x increases, increases the slope value. So how, provided with the slope value, can I distinguish if it is more 'slope' or it just further on x axis.

Comment: @JanisTaranda there's one derivative for each axis. I don't really understand your second question, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: With equation g′(x)=2x, if increase x, the slope value (result) increases. Like if x = 1, g′(x) = 2; x = 5, g′(x) = 10; etc. So it grows nerveless slope is the same. It also grows when then slope is more tilted up. So how can I distinguish when getting from the function a single float for the axis? I hope I made the question clear.

Comment: Or maybe to simplify (or the end result I want). How does one calculate normal's from slopes? :)

Comment: @JanisTaranda the slope is the change in y, so if the slope is `s` and the x difference is 1, then the direction vector is (1, s). To get the normal vector, you simply rotate by 90 degrees, which then gives you (-s, 1). Make sure to normalize it before using it thougj

Comment: Sorry I did not get the ` x difference is 1` part :).. what difference?

Comment: Can u give an example? When g′(x)=2x, and x is 4.. whats the normal vector and how it's calculated?

Comment: @JanisTaranda the slope is 8, the direction vector is (1, 8), normal is (-8, 1)

Comment: "the direction vector is (1, 8)". Why 1? Sorry for trolling

Comment: @JanisTaranda think about it, if you move 1 unit in the positive direction, a slope of 8 would mean going up 8 units.